# Problems with sIFR not displaying the correct text

Tags: javascript, jquery, sifr

I'm trying to use sIFR (with the jQuery sIFR plugin) on my website, but have run into problems right from the start. I was able to create the swf with my chosen font, but when I run the script, I just get the default "Rendered with sIFR3" message instead of the text of my element.

Any ideas?

---

As [Novemberborn himself](http://novemberborn.net/sifr3/r436) pointed out, I did upgrade sIFR to version 3, whereas the jQuery plugin only supports v2. I've tried reverting back to the packaged version of sIFR (v2.0.5):

My HTML:

```
<h1 class="img">Why should I do ELBC?</h1>
```

jQuery:

```
$(":header.img")
    .sifr({
        path : 'lib/sifr/2',
        font : 'test',
        width: 900,
        height: 60
    })
;
```

The `lib/sifr/2/test.swf` file is just the packaged `.fla` file compiled.

It looks like it's actually doing something this time: the correct text is showing up, but it's tiny. Like, 4pt size.

Comment: It might be helpful if you included some samples of the code+HTML you're using.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery plugin uses sIFR 2, however you seem to be using an (old) sIFR 3 movie.

Comment: I was having even less luck with the package from the jQuery plugin site, so I thought I'd try sIFR3. It was the latest release on the site (r436)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the swf file has been broken (e.g. during export).

You can determine this by replacing your swf file with one of the pre-built ones (distributed with sIFR) - this way you'll know whether the problem is in the javascript or in the flash. Either way - could you post more details?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I had the same problem and it took me a while to figure that it wasn't a problem with scripts or anything; it was simply incompatibility between the script being used and the swf.

Have a play with different export options to get them compatible - I use sifrgenerator.com to generate the swf file from the font. Hope it helps.

- Matt
  http://www.baradesign.com.au